# CountIF in Excel with a Variable Range for the Criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, countif, sumifs

I want to do a variation of CountIf() that tests the criteria against, not just one cell, but across a range of cells that corresponds to the range of cells being tested. Can I do this without creating an additional column?

For example, my spreadsheet looks something like this:

```
 X     Y
 4     3
 8     9
 6     6
 4     7
 2     1
```

I would like to count all the rows for which the value in X is greater than or equal to the value in Y. So, here the answer would be 3.

I'm aware of `countif(X1:X5,">="&Y1)`, but `countif(X1:X5,">="&Y1:Y5)` returns a value of "0". I could add an additional column, use an `if()` to test my criteria, and then sum that up; but, I have a lot of columns I'd like to do this for and would prefer not to clutter-up my spreadsheet.

Any suggestions on how I can do this in one function? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(X1:X5>=Y1:Y5))
```

It iterates both ranges together and counts the `True`